# Dual boot Windows 7 and macos High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, high-sierra, windows

I have a macbook pro retina 15 inch late 2013

I am running macos high sierra 10.13.3 and i want to install windows 7 and dual boot my macbook,
I have sucessfully created a bootable windows 7 usb drive with bootcamp 5 driver in  the pen drive,
When i start installing windows 7 bootcamp show me this message 
( Need 64-bit Windows installation USB drive or DVD.)

My windows usb installer have both 32 bit and 64 bit versions.[image]

I tried to solve my problem by following these steps, given in this link

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4747024

[image]

after following thsese steps bootcamp showing diffrent error ( Need 64 bit Windows 8 installataion USB drive or DVD

[image]

Comment: it is possible the installer either does not recognize it or wants the x64 version ONLY. You should be able to get that here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7

Comment: I have downloaded new iso file windows 7 ultimate 64 bit only. But the problem still exists Bootcamp still shows this error.

Comment: I note that your screen cap says it needs Windows EIGHT not 7. It may be that version of Bootcamp on your Mac no longer supports Windows 7. This version says it supports windows 7: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721?locale=en_US

Comment: So how can i install windows 7 on my macbook running macos high sierra 10.3.3

Comment: Use the version of BootCamp in the link above

Comment: I have downloaded this Bootcamp and copied it to my USB but still, bootcamp shows me this error ( Need 64 bit windows 8 installation USB  drive or DVD).